# Using CSS or JavaScript to count number of page breaks

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a very big HTML screen which when you print, prints over 16 pages so in Print Preview you can see page breaks. I am trying to display the page number like this:
Page X of Y

So display the page number out of the total number of pages and I am trying to display this in a footer that I created see below

```
        <!--New Footeer-->
<div id="footer">
                <p>Page X of Y</p>
</div>
<!--End New Footer-->
```

But is there a way in either CSS or JavaScript which I can use to achieve this? E.g. a way to count page breaks?

Comment: Give smitrovic a "correct answer" tick and an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@page {
   @bottom-right {
    content: counter(page) " of " counter(pages);
   }
}
```

This will print out what you want just with CSS

Comment: How do I get it to display in the footer I created?

Comment: Try:
#footer{
    content: counter(page) " of " counter(pages);
   }
This will add that content element to footer.

Comment: Does this have browser compatibility issues? because it does not seem to work no matter what browser I try - nothing appears

Comment: This is print property, so it is visible only on print media.

Comment: The major browser no longer supports `@bottom-right` property.